# Trouble with setting self delegate in order to hide keyboard when return is pressed

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to set a text field as a delegate to hide the keyboard when return is pressed

```
[self.velocityTextField setDelegate:self];
```

This is compiling, but it is giving me a semantic issuse. What is the proper way to do this?

Here is the method for hiding the keyboard:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What's the semantic issue?

Comment: @Cristik "sending "viewController *const__strong' parameter of incompatible type 'id<uiTextFieldDelegate>'"

Answer (score 0):

Even if you implement `textFieldShouldReturn` your view controller (self) is not a UITextField delegate, modify your controller definition this way:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

That's the reason why you get that `Sending 'viewController *const__strong' parameter of incompatible type 'id<uiTextFieldDelegate>'`

Comment: Sorry, don't *add* that, i meant modify the interface definition you already have :)